# Obligation to thank and/or respect

Tags: ethics

I'm just curious about some questions.

(1) Please suppose a situation where you enter to college as a freshman. One day a senior comes to you and says: "I have entered this school earlier than you and done some contribution to this school (e.g. paying tuition). It means that because of me you can study in better environment. Therefore, it is proper that you must thank (and/or respect) me".

Do you think this is a sound argument? Do we owe something to that senior? **Is it problematic if I say some bad words to that senior?**

(2) Also, in a similar context, please suppose a situation where you are born at a country. One day an old man comes to you and says: "I have born at this country earlier than you and done some contribution to this country (e.g. participating at a war, working, etc.). It's the reason you can be born and live in good environment. Therefore, younger generation has to thank to older generation.

Do you think this is a sound argument? Do we have an obligation to respect older generation?

In both cases, I think one can make this view: "According to our observation, no one chooses one's own birth. Therefore, obligation to thank/respect is at one's parents." Because there are country in advance, one's parents were able to have a child. Because there are college in advance, their child could enter to college.

Also I wonder the following: Isn't it that gratitude is only valid when someone does something to us **in good will**? For example, let's suppose that there is a country where military service is **mandatory**. In this case, can soldiers be a subject to be thanked? I think one can say: "No, soldiers are not a subject to be thanked. It's because military service is their duty. In other words, military service is just what **we** have to do. Everybody is expected to fulfill their duty. It is just a natural thing and natural things can't be thanked, by definition."

Thank you for reading this long question. It would be greatly appreciated if you share some of your opinion/knowledge.

Comment: Minor point of clarification - you used the word "gratitude" at one point. Are you seeing "gratitude" and "obligation to respond positively" as the same thing here?  It is possible that one might understood "gratitude" as simply "accepting and acknowledging something as a valuable gift", but I know another definition might interpret it as involving some degree of reciprocity or restitution, so just wanting to be clear about what you see as "gratitude".

Comment: Hello first thank you for the clarification. I have no background on philosophy and ethics so it was impossible for me to understand entirely what you've said... but I think I used the term 'gratitude' as 'accepting and acknowledging something as a valuable gift'. I think the reason I just thanked to you is because you are trying to solve my curiosity in kind heart. I used 'gratitude' in this meaning.